# Troubble getting the footer stay in the bottom of the page 4

Tags: footer

im new here, I have a page http://www.worldbellydancefestival.com/dance-costumes that the footer can not properly stay on the bottom, i've added clear to the footer block but it is not working. could you please help. many thanks.

the footer css:

```
#footer{
    width: 980px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*border-top:1px solid #ce09d0;*/
/*  padding-bottom:20px;*/
    background:url(/images/nav-bg-blk0.png) repeat 0 100%;
    max-height: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some code and describe what you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: thanks Alexander, I've pasted the footer css.